# Add support for an embedded audio player

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I've noticed that a lot of times on this site, questions are asked about how to modify a particular sound or about the availability of particular sounds.  Often, this requires the audio to be externally hosted and reduces the usefulness of the question and almost all usefulness to some answers if the link ever goes dead.

Would it be possible to get some kind of support for limited audio hosting similar to the image support through imgur so that we could have a reliable, long term way to include audio clips in the site?

Answer (score 7):

*Testing… Testing… Posting link to `http://soundcloud.com/digitechfx/digitech-bad-monkey-demo-1`*

### Yes!

It is already possible to embed YouTube and [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/) content in your posts. Simply include a link to the SoundCloud or YouTube page you want, and a player will be embedded in your post automatically.

We don't have it as tightly integrated into the editor as adding a picture, but we have a similar arrangement with SoundCloud so the links do not go dead without cause.

Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Hi, Robert, can you detail "similar arrangement with SoundCloud"? How does it work to prevent link rot?